# socket select fails with operation in progress - Non blocking mode

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

Our application uses a non-blocking socket usage with connect and select operations (c code).
The pusedo code is as below

```
unsigned int ConnectToServer(struct sockaddr_in *pSelfAddr,struct sockaddr_in *pDestAddr)
{
    int sktConnect = -1;

    sktConnect = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sktConnect == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return -1;


    fcntl(sktConnect,F_SETFL,fcntl(sktConnect,F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
    if(pSelfAddr != 0)
    {
        if(bind(sktConnect,(const struct sockaddr*)(void *)pSelfAddr,sizeof(*pSelfAddr)) != 0)
        {
            closesocket(sktConnect);
            return -1;
        }
    }


    errno = 0;
    int nRc = connect(sktConnect,(const struct sockaddr*)(void *)pDestAddr, sizeof(*pDestAddr));
    if(nrC != -1)
    {
        return sktConnect;
    }

    if(errno != EINPROGRESS)
    {
        int savedError = errno;
        closesocket(sktConnect);
        return -1;
    }

    fd_set scanSet;
    FD_ZERO(&scanSet);
    FD_SET(sktConnect,&scanSet);

    struct timeval waitTime;
    waitTime.tv_sec = 2;
    waitTime.tv_usec = 0;

    int tmp;
    tmp = select(sktConnect +1, (fd_set*)0, &scanSet, (fd_set*)0,&waitTime);
    if(tmp == -1 || !FD_ISSET(sktConnect,&scanSet))
    {
        int savedErrorNo = errno;
        writeLog("Connect %s failed after select, cause %d, error %s",inet_ntoa(pDestAddr->sin_addr),savedErrorNo,strerror(savedErrorNo));
        closesocket(sktConnect);
        return -1;
    }

    .   
    .   
    .
    .
    .}
```

---

**Problem statement**
In the above code, the `select` fails with `error code 115` which is "Operation in progress". I do not see any documentation on `select` failing with `errno 115`.

a. When does the `select` fails with `error code 115` in non-blocking socket? Under what scenario?
b. Do we see any system logs which hints at this problem. Only concern for us me - I could not find any documented feature which describes such problem.

---

PS : We are using SUSE Linux 11 Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Some thoughts on your code:***

I think your condition below the select can be modified to check only to see, if select has returned a value greater than 0 and if that is the case, you can check output of getsockopt for the socket (for SOL_SOCKET and SO_ERROR) options (`getsockopt(...,SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR,...,...)`) to see if connect has not failed.

I am not very sure if the select will always return the socket as writable in case of a connection success. So, in your case, it may (**only may**) be the case that, the tmp variable is not -1 and the errno it is showing is the errno of the previous connect call.

***Additional Reasons:***

Another good reason is that, the destination address to which you are connecting is either not reachable, or doesn't have a server waiting at the specified address + port combination. In which case, you can try once with a blocking socket to see if that connects.

Comment: Doesn't the call to select reset the value of errno? I was under the assumption it is reset before every system call.

Comment: In my experience atleast I haven't seen system calls resetting errno. errno will be overwritten by another error incase of failure.

Comment: select() is *defined* to return a socket as writable when a connection succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

The errno EINPROGRESS isn't from select(), it is left over from the prior connect() operation. You enter the block that reports it if *either* select() returned -1 *or* the FD isn't set. All this means is that the connection is still in progress. errno is never cleared, only set.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are trying to make a connection with timeout.

If so, there is a error in your code. After `connect()` call but before `select()` you should remove `O_NONBLOCK` option using `fcntl()`. Otherwise the `select()` will always return at once because the operations with your socket (which has `O_NONBLOCK`) would not block.

The EINPROGRESS which you read is probably generated not by `select()` but by previous `connect()` call.

You also should not use `bind()` call here because `connect()` implicitly binds your address to socket.

Comment: `select()` is unaffected by `O_NONBLOCK` and `bind()` may still be useful to use a fixed source address rather than the one chosen by the kernel.

Comment: One correct statement out of three. You are wrong about the 'error in your code' concerning blocking mode; right about the errno; and irrelevant about binding.