# SuSE Linux network exception system log files

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming

I had posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151140/socket-select-fails-with-operation-in-progress-non-blocking-mode) on behaviour of network under heavy congestion. As a follow up question, I want to understand below aspects

- Assume that the application with such code is present at deployment environment, what is the best way to prove to user that the issue is because of network congestion. My real question is: Is there a system level network activity logging mechanism (at least for the exception cases)?
- Is there any other indirect method of proving the same to the user? Meaning any command under such system activity which can take specific information about the system network activity.

PS: I know that there are really good tools out there which will help us in such scenario. However, since the problem is occurring in deployment area, we are restricted to using system provided default tools and log.

Any suggestion/study link in this regard will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a system level network activity logging mechanism?

Yes, there is. Take a look into [syslog](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog). You should define in your application with what level do you want to log each message.

> Is there any other indirect method of proving the same to the user?

That depends. If you have a GUI, then you can pop a message box with appropriate warning text.